# How to call a IPv6 REST service over AWS Lambda

Tags: java, aws-lambda, ipv6, alexa-skills-kit

I've got an Alexa Skill hosted in AWS Lambda which uses `AsyncHttpClient` to call an `IPv6` REST service under the following EXAMPLE URL:

```
http://[2a12:5375:4151:2300:1353:a632:5f4e:c232]:4711/rest/test
```

Now my problem is, that I always get the following exception:

```
ava.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Protocol family unavailable
```

If I check the IP address which is assigned to the underlying server or the application?, I get the following address (also example):

```
ip-10-23-56-1.eu-west-1.compute.internal: 10.23.56.1
```

So I think, because I am using an IPv6 while the system uses IPv4, I can't get it working? 
I can call my REST service from another server successfully.

I am also using the following system properties:

```
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Addresses", "true");
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "false");
```

Is there any solution to provide a 'tunnel' over the IPv4 underlying system to tunnel the IPv6 address to call the REST service? Or is there any simpler solution?

Comment: You cannot access IPv6 addresses from an IPv4 only place (unless you use certain tunneling software like Teredo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, AWS have added IPv6 support to AWS Lambda service but it is not enabled by default; that is the reason you still get those errors.

You need to configure a custom VPC. You can find more details at https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/10/aws-lambda-ipv6-outbound-connections-vpc/

Answer (score 5):

The error `Protocol family unavailable` means that the protocol (in this case IPv6) is not available or not configured on the system on which your code is running.

In the case of AWS, the only thing you can do about this is to complain and hope they eventually roll out IPv6 support to services which don't yet have it.

Comment: Just for info: I got a VirtualServer which can handle both, I use this server as a REST Proxy to let this IPv6 compatible server handle the requests and proxy them through ;)

Answer (score 1):

After quite an extensive research and tests the word is: IPv6 is not available for Lambda. This goes a bit further if you run your Lambda functions inside a VPC.

If your function is associated with a subnet that includes IPv6 CIDR then no amount of correct config will get your Lambda to access external resources.

You will be able to do API calls to some of the AWS resources available as VPC endpoints. This includes services like S3 and Dynamo, they will get an internal IP within your VPC. Services like SQS are not supported under VPC endpoint so will get external resolution.

Any service or external API call that goes outside your VPC will fail with IPv6 CIDR. The only way to go around this is to remove IPv6 CIDR from the subnet or create a dedicated subnets just for your Lambda functions.

We have opted for the latter option and all is working great with appropriate VPC security and routing policies applied.